# To join 2 views using a nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join 2 views using the column b and d, which are nvarchar columns.

```
View 1      View 2
A | B      D | E 
w  0090    90   c
q  qw      qw  b 
z  004     4   v
l  T-Q     T-Q n
```

Now, have joined the columns B and D. Here since they are nvarchar columns 009 doesn't match with 9. Only records that have numbers in them have multiple 0's before the number in view 1, which do not match with the numbers in view 2 as they don't have any 0's, but the value is the same.

I want a join condition in which this matches. Converting to int is not viable as I have alphabets as well in that field.

Comment: You need to provide more information on what is and isn't a match.

Comment: You'll likely need a string function, but I doubt there is one that will easily work for the entire views.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Any specific information you looking for?

Comment: @AaronDietz String function will be very risky as some records will join with other records that won't provide the right output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this suit your needs? Not sure if it will cover all scenarios or not. The first `ON` will get `INT` matches, the second will get everything else that matches.

```
DECLARE @View1 TABLE (A NVARCHAR(10), B NVARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @View2 TABLE (D NVARCHAR(10), E NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @View1 VALUES ('w','009'),('q','qw')
INSERT INTO @View2 VALUES ('9','c'),('qw','b')

SELECT *
FROM @View1 a
JOIN @View2 b 
    ON TRY_CONVERT(INT,a.B) = TRY_CONVERT(INT,b.D)
    OR a.B = b.D
```

Comment: Does this convert all records to an int value.

Comment: note: [**`try_convert()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) is sql server 2012+, and will return `null` for values that do not convert to the specified type.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Prior to SQL Server 2012+ you could use this to replace any leading `0`s:

```
select v1.*, v2.*
from v1
  inner join v2
    on stuff(v1.b,1,patindex('%[^0]%',v1.b)-1,'')
      = v2.d
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CEFA74351

returns:

```
+---+-----+-----+---+
| a |  b  |  d  | e |
+---+-----+-----+---+
| w | 009 | 9   | c |
| q | qw  | qw  | b |
| z | 004 | 4   | v |
| l | T-Q | T-Q | n |
+---+-----+-----+---+
```

---

The above would not match `0` and `0`, one workaround replaces `null` values with `0`. If the column can have `null` values then this workaround would not be appropriate as it would match existing nulls to `0`.

```
select v1.*, v2.*
from v1
  inner join v2
    on isnull(stuff(v1.b,1,patindex('%[^0]%',v1.b)-1,''),'0')
      = v2.d
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OTCI42982

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I would use `REPLACE()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM View1 V1
INNER JOIN View2 V2 on REPLACE(V1.B,'0','') = V2.D
```

Comment: wouldn't that cause `90` to  `= 9` as well?

Comment: @SqlZim Yeah.  Heavy stress upon *based on the example*

Comment: there are zeroes after the numbers as well. Thanks though, it was my bad that I didn't specify that.